# Can I travel on a UK passport with a maiden name?

Tags: uk, passports

I'm looking for definitive/official sources to back up an answer, e.g. GOV UK website.

Anecdotally, it seems that as long as the name of the passport matches with the name on the flight tickets, a maiden name is fine.

[The GOV UK website](https://www.gov.uk/changing-passport-information/name-marriage-and-civil-partnership) suggests that you can change your name on the passport, but doesn't make it clear whether you must.

Comment: I can't speak for UK specifically, but if you couldn't it would make honeymoon travel difficult!  My wife was told that as long as tickets matched the passport there should be no issues, but to take a copy of the marriage certificate in case there are any questions (or if any bookings were in married names etc).  We never had any issues in several years of travel while using her maiden name passport.  When it expired she got one in her married name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no legal requirement in the UK to change your name upon marriage (or divorce). All that matters is that reservations where you are required to provide your passport as ID match your name in the passport.
https://www.ukdp.co.uk/name-change-marriage/

Comment: What you and this link seem to be saying is that the name is not legally changed with the marriage certificate, and so there's no need to update the passport at least until the name is legally changed. Is that accurate?

Comment: @AJarofClay I think you need to consult a lawyer if you think there is an issue here but what the answer says is what I also believe to be the law.

Comment: @AJarofClay You have several options, as the link explains, ranging from changing your name and all associated documents/records (passport, DL, bank accounts etc) immediately, to keeping your maiden name the same (forever, or until you decide to change it),  It’s up to you. I’ve kept my ex-husband’s family name for nearly 20 tears, since we divorced (ie never changed my passport name back to my maiden nane, or my bank accounts/credit cards etc).